# Cannot create a sub project when using the Diagnostics solution template

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-2015

I installed

- Visual Studio 2015 RC
- Visual Studio 2015 RC SDK
- .NET Compiler Platform SDK Templates
- .NET Compiler Platform Syntax Visualizer

However when I now try to create a "Diagnostic with Code Fix" I receive this error:

> A problem was encountered creating the sub project. The imported project "`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.5.2\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets`" was not found.

Afterwards I receive two more error messages which seem to stem from this. These error messages occur as VS is trying to create the other projects in the solution template.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I look at the folder in question, I see this structure:

[image]

I copied the contents of v4.6 and put it in a folder named v4.5.2 which indeed resolved the problem when creating the projects, but this causes build errors: System.Runtime isn't added to the projects and manually adding it causes Visual Studio to crash and the projects to become invalid.

I already repaired the entire installation, which didn't make a difference. Visual Studio 2013 runs alongside 2015.

I assume I must be missing a vital component but I can't find any indication as to what that might be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the target framework version at the top of the new project dialog to 4.5 before creating the project.

Comment: Perfect, using 4.5 works. I wasn't even aware of this dropdown menu. I also tried using 4.6 but that didn't work: upon re-opening the solution it says the analyzer project requires an update. If I then rightclick and click "download update" it redirects me to a 404 page at microsoft.com. Is this expected behaviour because I'm lacking something, or is it something I should file a bug for?

Comment: Since we forked for RC, we've actually changed the templates to hard-code 4.5 instead of listening to the dialog, since that won't work properly for Portable Class Library projects, which the analyzer is.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using these templates

- .NET Compiler Platform SDK Templates
- .NET Compiler Platform Syntax Visualize

Are they the [RC templates](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e2e07e91-9d0b-4944-ba40-e86bcbec1599)

Or the [Preview templates](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/849f3ab1-05cf-4682-b4af-ef995e2aa1a5) from November?

I ask because there was a bug that caused you to reference the wrong portable targets in the Preview templates, but that should be fixed for RC.